# not equals isnt working in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, nullable, query-builder, comparison-operators

I couldnt get the not equals condition to work. What happens is that it is ignoring all data as the `cancelled_by` field has been `null`. If the `cancelled_by` field is `null` then that does not equate to not equals `Tutor`.

This little error has cost me 5 days of wrong data. Is there a mistake I am making? Once I removed the not equals condition, all the data was retrieved as expected.

The 2 lines below is what I used and neither worked.

```
'Lessons.cancelled_by not like' => '%Tutor%'   

'Lessons.cancelled_by !=' => 'Tutor'
```

```
$searchDate = date('Y-m-d');

$query3 = $this->find()
    ->contain([
        'Tutors', 'Subjects', 'Students', 'Students.Guardians', 'XeroInvoices'
    ])
    ->select([
        'Lessons.id', 'Lessons.lesson_date', 'Lessons.start_time', 'Lessons.end_time',
        'Tutors.id', 'Tutors.first_name', 'Guardians.id', 'Tutors.last_name',
        'Lessons.timesheet_status', 'Students.id', 'Students.first_name',
        'Students.last_name', 'Students.has_credit', 'XeroInvoices.invoice_number',
        'Guardians.guardian_email', 'Guardians.guardian_mobile',
        'Guardians.guardian_last_name', 'Guardians.guardian_first_name',
        'Lessons.due_date', 'Lessons.cancelled_by', 'Subjects.name', 'Lessons.revenue',
        'Lessons.discount', 'Lessons.surcharge', 'Lessons.future_makeup_lesson_id',
        'Lessons.cancelled_pastlesson_id'
    ])
    ->where([
        'Lessons.due_date' => $searchDate,
        'Lessons.lesson_inactive' => false,
        'Students.has_credit like' => '%postpaid%',
        'Lessons.cancelled_by !=' => 'Tutor'
    ])
    ->order([
        'Guardians.id',
        'Lessons.lesson_date' => 'ASC',
        'Lessons.start_time' => 'ASC'
    ])
    ->hydrate(false);
```

Comment: Equality operators don't interact well with null values in SQL in general. You should probably add an "OR" condition with `'cancelled_by IS' => NULL`, or `IS NOT`, as appropriate.

Comment: This is not related to PHP. In SQL language `NULL` does not equal anything by definition.

Comment: if I understood the problem then I wouldnt be asking for help, and I wouldnt be posting this in cakephp3.

Comment: @jagguy Sorry if I offended you, my only intention was to provide information about the root problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'Lessons.cancelled_by !=' => 'Tutor'` is correct but it wont work for null values.
`'Lessons.cancelled_by IS NOT' => 'NULL'` would work for NULL values instead. I think you can use both. So the result will only be (cancelled_by != 'Tutor' AND cancelled_by IS NOT NULL) which is the result you needed.

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct answer by a poster here. If that person could place the answer here.Equality operators don't interact well with null values in SQL in general. You should probably add an "OR" condition with 'cancelled_by IS' => NULL, or IS NOT, as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Use **->notEq()**

example

```
$query = $articles->find()
    ->where(function ($exp) {
        return $exp
            ->eq('author_id', 2)
            ->eq('published', true)
            ->notEq('spam', true)
            ->gt('view_count', 10);
    });
```

Read more here [Cakephp 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)

Comment: How is that supposed to solve problems with `NULL` values? `notEq()` will produce the exact same comparison as shown in the question, ie it will create a `!=` operator.